# Destination unreacheable (Android mobile)

Tags: android

I have coded a Web call, but when i want to try my Android application into the Android device, the response is a socket exception "unreachable destination" (in my mobile device), but if i try with Android Simulator works well (no problems, no exception). My mobile device is connected via UMTS to the service provider, no WIFI.

My Android model and firmware is the following:

HTC Magic
Firmware: 1.6.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a network issue, can you check the following:

1. Is the address you are connecting to on the internet, and not on your LAN?
2. Can you connect to other addresses on the phone in your program?
3. Can you connect to other addresses on the phone outside of your program? (Browser, etc.)
4. Can you connect to the address on the phone outside of your program? (Browser, etc.)

Comment: 1. It's an IP public.
2. My own application (when I try on phone) connects without problems to login application page in my Server. But the problem appears with another pages into the domain.
3. Yeah! I have tried with www.google.com (No problems)
4. Yes, I can.

Problem persist...

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere. So the problem only occurs when you are accessing pages other then your main page, on the phone, and only on your application. Can you post the code that you are using to make the request in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable internet permissions in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Sorry, but this permission was already inserted into the manifest...

Another suggestion?